# Resizing ImageView after circle cropping

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got some rectangular images I'm trying to crop down in to circular ImageViews without distortion. I've created a custom ImageView and here's the onDraw() method

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight(), radius = 0;

    if (w < h) {
        radius = w;
    } else {
        radius = h;
    }

    Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, radius);
    if (w < h) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, (float)(h-w)/2, null);
    } else {
        canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, (float)(w-h)/2, 0, null);
    }
}
```

All of this, is working perfectly in cropping the bitmap with the shortest side as my radius. However, the actual image view in the layout is maintaining the rectangular size and screwing up the rest of of my layout with the extra padding depending on image orientation.

If I have an image that's say 40x80, I want the image cropped down to a radius of 40 and the width scaled down to 40x40 square. Same for 80x40.

I tried to call setScaleX or setScaleY but it requires API 11 and I need to support back to 2.3 for now. Is there another way to force the layout views down.